Defining a grid in tikz using setlength vs. explicitly setting a length parameter
I am trying to create a grid on a page using tikz that covers the entire page from one corner to another with a ratio of pagewidth/pageheigth.
I managed to create such a grid as follows:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage[margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}
    
\begin{document}    
\noindent   

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, x=\pagewidth/30, 
y=\pageheight/30, yshift=\pageheight/90]        
\draw[step=1] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

However, this does not allow me to use the defined unit lengths' as dimensions (e.g. in minimum width=3 instead of minimum width=3*\pagewidth/30 or something like minimum width=3cm).
When I tried defining lengths using \newlength and \setlength as in the following code, the result is a completely different grid.
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}

\newlength{\x}
\setlength{\x}{\pagewidth/30}

\newlength{\y}
\setlength{\y}{\pageheight/30}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,x=\x,y=\y,yshift=\y/3]
        \draw[step=1] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Can anyone explain to me, why the results are not identical? The definition seems to be the same mathematically, so I fail to understand the difference.

On a sidenote: I noticed there is a lot of manual pushing around the grid required for it to actually start at the top right hand corner, for which I have no logical explanation and did not find one after searching for a while. One should be able to assume that current page.north west is defined decently obviously, but that is apparently not the case. I have not found a good explanation, so if anyone can help get rid of the yshift and noindent that would be much appreciated. Similarly, the font size 12pt seems to be important for grid positioning (it is shifted for, e.g., 10pt, so where is my misunderstanding of the anchor name in the first place?

Note the \pagewidth iand \pageheight are peculiar to LuaLaTeX, although they are also set by geometry.  See also \paperwidth and \paperheight.

This is because at the time where you set the lengths of \x and \y in the second example, the paper size has not been set yet by geometry. So, the default paper size is used.
You can delay the setting of the lengths via \AtBeginDocument like in the following example:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}

\newlength{\x}
\newlength{\y}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength{\x}{\pagewidth/30}
    \setlength{\y}{\pageheight/30}
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,x=\x,y=\y,yshift=\y/3]
        \draw[step=1] (current page.north west) grid (current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The output should be about the same as in your first example.

If you want to actually have a grid placed at the background of your page (which I assume is what you want) and have it exactly aligned at the top left corner, you can also use the shipout/background hook (note that you don't need remember picture then):
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,a3paper]{geometry}

\newlength{\x}
\newlength{\y}
\AtBeginDocument{
    \setlength{\x}{\pagewidth/30}
    \setlength{\y}{\pageheight/30}
}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,x=\x,y=\y]
        \draw[step=1] (0,0) grid (\pagewidth,-\pageheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \null
\end{document}


Just to say that I definitely read your answer before answering. But I may not have reread it before responding to the comment on mine.

Jasper's answer explains the problem and offers an effective solution, but you don't really need tikz for this. You can just use the kernel's picture commands since the shipout/background hook already puts you inside a picture environment. Moreover, this method does not require a second compilation to position things correctly. If you wish, you can even dispense with calc. I did that below, though I probably wouldn't bother generally. calc is lightweight and saves the clutter of \dimexpr everywhere.
Note that I also renamed the lengths since it is bad practice to use single letter names globally. (But it isn't terrible as long as you stick to \newcommand.)

I'd also recommend using a3paper as a class option so scrartcl knows, even if you are overriding its layout with geometry.
Note that the origin is the top left corner of the page, so y typically requires negative values.
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{scrartcl}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726247/
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}

\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \newlength\xgridl
  \setlength\xgridl{\dimexpr\paperwidth/30}%
  \newlength\ygridl
  \setlength\ygridl{\dimexpr\paperheight/30}%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \multiput(0,0)(\xgridl,0){30}{\line(0,-1){\paperheight}}%
    \multiput(0,0)(0,-\ygridl){30}{\line(1,0){\paperwidth}}%
  }%
} 

\begin{document}
\mbox{ }
\end{document}

Edit
This is a modification of Jasper's second implementation.
If you wanted the grid on every page of a document, I would try something like the following if you need tikz:
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{scrartcl}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726247/
% addaswyd o ateb Jasper Habicht: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726223/
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\mypagegrid
\newlength\xgridl
\newlength\ygridl
\AddToHook{begindocument}{%
  \setlength\xgridl{\dimexpr\paperwidth/30}%
  \setlength\ygridl{\dimexpr\paperheight/30}%
  \sbox\mypagegrid{%
    \tikz[x=\xgridl,y=\ygridl,baseline=(o)]{%
      \draw [help lines,step=1] (0,0) coordinate (o) grid (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    }%
  }%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
    \put(0,0){\usebox{\mypagegrid}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\mbox{ }
\end{document}

If you want it on only some pages, you can use a one-time hook in a macro which you use to trigger the code on relevant pages.

Thank you for the explanation. You do raise a lot of valid points that I will remember for future projects. Just to let you know, why I did not accept your answer, even though it solves the problem more elegantly in a way: The reason, why I insisted on using tikz was that I use the grid to navigate the page and help me place other nodes (which I omitted from the question, as that was not relevant).

@MarkusG. thanks. it is pretty much accepted on this site to offer solutions which use other methods, at least once a question has an answer using the specified approach. you definitely don't need to feel obliged to explain why you don't accept them (though I certainly appreciate it). picture doesn't let you specify distinct x and y units, so there's definitely an advantage to using tikz in that case. it is possible to use \put to place the tikzpicture, which eliminates the need for remember and allows externalisation which reduces compilation time.

@MarkusG. To add to cfr's last comment: note that I did not use remember picture in the hook approach as it is not needed here. I only used overlay to create a zero-sized bounding box. So, it is essentially a tikzpicture in a \put command ... =)

@JasperHabicht, my apologies I should have reread your answer before making that comment.

@MarkusG. I'm assuming you only want the grid on one page. If not, I'd recommend combining Jasper's hook with a box so you can render the grid exactly once and then just reuse the box on every page which needs it. (But you do have to get rid of the remember for this to work.) I doubt you need overlay here, but I've not checked.

@cfr No, you are still right and I made this clear in my question only now. In fact, I missed to remove remember picture in my original answer, so there is a chance that you read this version (which existed one or two hours) before writing your answer which is totally valid! No apologies please!

A box approach is an even nicer idea actually! This is how things should go on this site: You stitch together the best ideas from all the answers you get to your question =)
